# UnauthorizedAccessException when creating a mutex

Tags: .net, multithreading, winapi, mutex

Given the following piece of code that uses a Mutex :

```
string mutexName = @"Global\MyMutex";

try
{
    _mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting(mutexName, MutexRights.Synchronize);
}
catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException)
{
    SecurityIdentifier securityIdentifier = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
    MutexSecurity mutexSecurity = new MutexSecurity();
    mutexSecurity.AddAccessRule(new MutexAccessRule(securityIdentifier, MutexRights.Synchronize, AccessControlType.Allow));

    bool dummy = false;

    // Creates the internal Mutex without taking ownership on it.
    _mutex = new Mutex(false, mutexName, out dummy, mutexSecurity);
}
```

For some of my users, when the Mutex gets created (in the catch block), an UnauthorizedAccessException is thrown. I'm trying to find what cause this exception.

The message is

> Access to the path 'Global\MyMutex' is denied.

I know that some of the users having the problem are not administrator of their pc.
I've read on MSDN about Mutex and MutexAccessRule, but it is not clear to me where I can assign or see permissions related to Mutex for a given user.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is not the Mutex rights, but the right to create objects in Global\ namespace (SeCreateGlobalPrivilege).

Also, if this code can be called by multiple processes at about the same time - you can have a race condition here.

Comment: For SeCreateGlobalPrivilege, it is verry interesting.
After reading about SeCreateGlobalPrivilege, am I wrong or I can't set this privilege at runtime in my application ? 

Another thing, this privilege seems to apply only to users in terminal services sessions who are not administrator, local system account or service account?

Comment: At first, I though you were talking about thread racing but in fact, you're right. This code is used for inter process communication. So I need to fix the process racing issue.

How should I protect the code against that?